# Unable to simplify the real part of a complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Simplifying this expression shouldn't be hard. I tried adding assumptions asserting that all involved variables are real, but still the `Re` expression remains

```
Simplify[
  Re[
    (I (E^(I (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])) + 3 I ϵ) ϵ) /
      ((E^(2 I (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])) + 2 ϵ^2) σx^2) + 
    (E^(I (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0]))y^2 ϵ (-I E^(2 I (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])) + 
      6 E^(I (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])) ϵ + 2 I ϵ^2)) / 
        ((E^(2 I (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])) + 2 ϵ^2)^2 σx^2 σy^2)]
  /. 
    {Exp[I (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])] -> 
       Cos[(t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])] + I Sin[(t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])], 
     Exp[I 2 (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])] -> 
       Cos[2 (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])] + I Sin[2 (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0])]},   
  t ∈ Reals && ω ∈ Reals && Subscript[ϕ, 0] ∈ Reals && 
  (t ω + Subscript[ϕ, 0]) ∈ Reals && σx ∈ Reals && σy ∈ Reals && ϵ ∈ Reals]
```

[image: unable to simplify further]

As you will see if you remove the substitutions, the `Exp` does not get simplified to `Sin + I Cos` expressions unless it is done manually.

I tried running `FullSimplify`, but it just stalls indefinitely. I had to abort the evaluation after 10 minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Re[(I (E^(I (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])) + 3 I ε) ε)/
  ((E^(2 I (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])) + 2 ε^2) σx^2) + (E^(I (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])) y^2
  ε (-I E^(2 I (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])) +  6 E^(I (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])) ε + 2 I ε^2))/
  ((E^(2 I (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])) + 2 ε^2)^2 σx^2 σy^2)] /.
  {Exp[I (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])] ->
     Cos[(t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])] + I Sin[(t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])],
   Exp[I 2 (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])] ->
     Cos[2 (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])] + I Sin[2 (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])]}]]
```

yields

```
(ε (-12 ε^3 (-2 y^2 + σy^2 + 2 ε^4 σy^2) +3 ε (y^2 (2 + 8 ε^4) - (1 + 12 ε^4)
σy^2) Cos[2 (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])] - 6 ε^3 σy^2 Cos[4 (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])] +
(y^2 (-1 + 4 ε^2 + 8 ε^4 - 8 ε^6) + (1 - 4 ε^2 + 8 ε^4 - 8 ε^6) σy^2) Sin[t Ω +
Subscript[Φ, 0]] + 2 ε^2 (y^2 + 2 y^2 ε^2 + σy^2 -2 ε^2 σy^2) Sin[3 (t Ω +
Subscript[Φ, 0])]))/(σx^2 σy^2 (1 + 4 ε^4 + 4 ε^2 Cos[2 (t Ω + Subscript[Φ, 0])])^2)
```

Comment: ComplexExpand did the trick, it works even with Simplify

Answer (score 2):

Adding an ExpToTrig@ before your Simplify gives the result without replacement.